# Wordpress page title only fixed in 4.6.4?

Tags: wordpress

Can I assume that the fix mentioned in this post is for 4.6.4 NOT 4.6.3, the current stable version?

http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,36339.msg154556.html#msg154556

Any idea how long until 4.6.4 is the stable version or what magic happens in that version to allow Wordpress to use the title of the PCP for the page title (instead of the site title)?

Comment: The core team works very hard to provide regular point releases around the first and third Wednesday of each month (https://civicrm.org/blogs/totten/release-policy-and-new-release-candidates ), and you can get nightly builds from http://dist.civicrm.org/by-date/ . Also see http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/Developing+with+the+CiviCRM+team and http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/CiviCRM+Roadmap for more information.

Comment: @choster I think this comment would make a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On reviewing the situation in the presence of various plugins that try and change the title for SEO or Open Graph reasons, I think there is an issue with the way Civi tries to set the title. I've created at pull request on the [CiviCRM WordPress plugin's repo at GitHub](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-wordpress/pull/78) that should fix this.

Answer (score 2):

The forum post indicates that it was already fixed in the 4.6.0 version of civicrm. Please read the forum topic closely, specifically haystack's and coleman's reply here:

http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,36339.msg154574.html#msg154574

If you need to backport a patch to your existing version, this document will be of help:

http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Verify+a+bug+fix

Comment: I guess I have a bigger issue then. My site which is 4.6.3 does not show page titles when viewing pages thru Civi URL (as opposed to a shortcode in a WP page). I did test it in the Twenty Thirteen theme that is used on the demo site and no dice. I poked around other settings in WordPress (permalinks, uninstalled plugins) but haven't been able to get them working.  Any ideas how else I can test and get this working.

Comment: can you try and test the same thing on the demo server and see if it actually does the right thing (as the forum topic suggests). Would be good to confirm that

Comment: The Wordpress Demo, which is 4.6.4 works fine - I tried a PCP, Conribution and an event - all display the page title properly.

Comment: I would try disabling all non-civi related WP plugins and see if that helps on your site. Also do all your testing / experiments with the 2013 theme

Comment: Started there, I'm all too familiar with a plug-in breaking something! I've removed all my custom templates, custom php functions, even styling (yes, I know that shouldn't have anything to do with it but since I was testing). Still no dice. I am going to try a fresh install of 4.6.3 to see what that gets me. (I was in WP 4.2.2 so maybe that's the problem, I'll try both 4.1.2 and see where I land....)

Comment: What code is your theme using to display titles? Can you post the code from 'header.php' here?

Comment: Hi Guys - I just tried a fresh install of wordpress 4.2.2, twenty thirteen theme, with a fresh install of Civi 4.6.3 and I loaded sample data.  You can see here that the page titles still don't work: http://test.blopphotography.com/cp/ongoing/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/register&reset=1&id=1  

@ChristianWach I think this is the pertinent code you're looking for  

<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>